# Confidence bounds on difference of sums

Tags: statistics

I am trying to get confidence bounds on the weighted sums of two buckets of iid normal random variables. I plotted the QQ plots using my variance estimate. The estimate works well for $N_A$, $N_B$ as low as  10 and 20 samples in A and B. But when the ratio of sample size of A and B are off by say 10x such as ($N_A = 100$ and $N_B = 1000$), the variance is overestimated. By 25% in the specific example.

For this experiment, two sets of random variables A, B are generated. I need to find the variance of a weighted sum of the two buckets $$s = \sum_{A}x - \sum_{B}x$$

The $\mu_C$ of each variable $x$ in the set $C = A U B$ is :

$$\mu_C = \frac{\sum_{A}x+\sum_{B}x}{N_A+N_B}$$

So $E[s]$:
$$\mu_s = \mu_C * (N_A-N_B)$$

The variance of s:
 $$v_s = \sum_{A}x^2 - \frac{(\sum_{A}x)^2}{N_A} +\sum_{B}x^2 - \frac{(\sum_{B}x)^2}{N_B}$$

I expect to see that $t$ here is a unit normal distributed:

$$t = \frac{E[s] - \mu_s}{\sqrt{ v_s * \frac{N_C-2}{N_C}}}$$

where $N_C = N_A+N_B$

Any idea why the variance is incorrect in the formula above when the ratio of $\frac{N_A}{N_B}$ is above 4 or so?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability if you format your questions using [*MathJax*](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, if this is HW, it should be tagged as such, so we can maintain statistics. Regards